# Im having useradd error in arch-linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, non-root-user, useradd

Im installing arch-linux for the first time and im following a video on youtube and im creating a non root user with the command

'' '**useradd -G wheel.audio.video - m nour11**'''
But im getting the error

'''**useradd : group wheel.audio.video does not exist**'''

Comment: Try separating the group names in the `-G` argument with comma characters not periods: `wheel,audio,video`

Answer (score 2):

As @steeldriver said in the comments, you just need to change the separator by a comma, ie:

```
useradd -G wheel,audio,video - m nour11
```

Don't hesitate to read the manual, in order to get more informations:

```
man useradd
```

Hope this helps :-)